# how to make CSS animation to play every 10 seconds

Tags: css, loops, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a css animation, which it either repeat infinite or only a certain times. but I would like to play it like 2 times every 5 seconds.
Here is my code:

```
    #countText{
    -webkit-animation-name: color2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes color2 {
        0% { }
        25% { text-shadow:-2px -5px 10px #fb0017, -5px 0px 10px #3a00cd, -5px 5px 10px #00ff3a}
        50% { }
        75% { text-shadow:2px 5px 10px #fb0017, 5px 0px 10px #3a00cd, 5px -5px 10px #00ff3a; }
        100% {}
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the keyframes to show animation twice. First from `0%` to `20%` and next from `20%` to `40%`, then let it stay like that till `100%`. Now change `animation-duration` to `5s` with no `animation-delay`

```
  #countText {
      -webkit-animation-name: color2;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes color2 {
      0% {
      }
      5%,25% {
          text-shadow: -2px -5px 10px #fb0017,
                       -5px 0px 10px #3a00cd,
                       -5px 5px 10px #00ff3a;
      }
      15%,35% {
          text-shadow: 2px 5px 10px #fb0017,
                       5px 0px 10px #3a00cd,
                       5px -5px 10px #00ff3a;
      }
      40% {
        text-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RSe8n/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.shk_this {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation-name: shakeMe;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes shakeMe {
  2%, 18% {
      transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  4%, 16% {
      transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
  }

  6%, 10%, 14% {
      transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  8%, 12% {
      transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  18.1% {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shk_this">Shake This</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).