# how to play CSS animation after every 5 seconds

Tags: css, loops, css-animations, css-transitions

I have created a CSS animation that I want to use as a page preloader. Right now the animation the working fine for a single iteration but I want to restart the animation from the start every 5 seconds after it completes. I want to play it like an infinite loop.

If I use iteration count infinite then each animation will start as soon as it completes, at that point the entire animation is still running. Is there any way to start the whole process like after every 5 or 6 seconds?

Please find the stackblitz editor URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-7tyxh5?file=styles.css

Comment: You can set `animation-iteration-count : infinite;` it will repeat after each duration finishes.

Comment: Its already answered checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element

Comment: This Question have been answered here is the link for the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783554/how-to-make-css-animation-to-play-every-10-seconds

Comment: you just set animation as `infinite`  and add `animation-delay: 5s`